# What node properties must exist for a clean graphml name in jQassistant

Tags: jqassistant

What properties must a node have, so that it's name is displayed in the graphml. grafic?

I create some node based on my packages with

```
MATCH (artifact:Artifact)
WHERE
   artifact.type <> "test-jar"
MATCH
  (artifact:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(root:Package{fqn:"net.sf.sze.dao.api"})-[:CONTAINS]->(slice:Package)
WITH COLLECT(slice) AS rows1
MATCH
  (artifact:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(root:Package{fqn:"net.sf.sze.frontend"})-[:CONTAINS]->(slice:Package)
WITH rows1 + COLLECT(slice) AS rows2
MATCH
  (artifact:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(root:Package{fqn:"net.sf.sze.service"})-[:CONTAINS *2..2]->(slice:Package)
WITH rows2 + COLLECT(slice) AS rows3
UNWIND rows3 AS slice
MERGE (sn:Slice{name:slice.name})
MERGE (sn)-[:SLICE_CONTAINS]-> (slice)
RETURN
  sn
```

and try to create a graphml diagram with

```
MATCH
  (slice1:Slice)-[:SLICE_CONTAINS]->()-[:CONTAINS*]->(t1:Type),
  (slice2:Slice)-[:SLICE_CONTAINS]->()-[:CONTAINS*]->(t2:Type),
  (t1)-[d:DEPENDS_ON]->(t2)
WHERE
   slice1 <> slice2
WITH
  slice1, slice2, count(d) as weight
RETURN
  slice1 as Slice1, slice2 as Slice2, {
    role :     "relationship",
    type :     "DEPENDS_ON",
    startNode: slice1,
    endNode:   slice2,
    properties: {
      weight: weight
    }
  } as Dependency
```

The graph is created well expect the node names. I only get as Label `CompositeObject, id = 123456` which makes the diagram useless.

Can anyone give me a hint, whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For types defined by the jQAssistant scanner there are type specific rules what will be rendered as a label, e.g. "fqn" for ":Artifact" labeled nodes.

You're creating a virtual relationship where the type cannot be determined thus no property can be shown. jQAssistant 1.3.0 will support a property "label" to control this, e.g.

```
  ....
RETURN
  slice1 as Slice1, slice2 as Slice2, {
    role :     "relationship",
    type :     "DEPENDS_ON",
    startNode: slice1,
    endNode:   slice2,
    label: weight, // set an explicit label
    properties: {
      weight: weight
    }
 } as Dependency
```

Comment: For which node is the label used? When will be 1.3.0 published? The :Artifact and `fqn` property solved it.

Comment: The label refers to the virtual element you're creating, in this case it's a relationship (role:"relationship"). 

jQAssistant 1.3.0 is already in the pipeline scheduled for mid/end of March 2017.

Comment: In my case I need a label for the nodes too.

Comment: The "label" property is also supported for virtual nodes and graphs.